# developing a learning system using neuro network

Tags: java, netbeans, artificial-intelligence, neural-network

hello please is it possible to develop a learning system based on neural network using Netbeans IDE and having success at the end? and what about blueJ, eclipse...which one do u recommend?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question, Netbeans, blueJ and eclipse are just IDE. The programming language is Java. Or do you want to use Netbeans platform for your buidling a GUI of your program?

Comment: Some might tell you that the IDE does not make a difference, but this is only because they don't know Emacs. This is what you have to master before having any hope of truly mastering the art of learning system development.

Answer (score 3):

You can use any IDE you want... you just need good algorithms, the IDE or language used does not really make much of a difference.